# Как объединить/увидеть пересечение множеств через цикл?

Tags: c#

Задали задачу: Ввести два множества и провести операции над ними (пересечение, объединение и тд) , с пересечением разобрался, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать объединение? (Использовать union нельзя, только цикл), код который есть сейчас:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Лабораторная4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n, count1 = 0;
            // ввод массивов
            Console.WriteLine("Введите размер множеств: ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] A = new int[n];
            Console.WriteLine("Введите множество А: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                A[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            int[] B = new int[n];
            Console.WriteLine("Введите множество В: ");
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                B[j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            // пересечение(и в том массиве встречается и в другом)
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int coutn = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (A[i] == B[j])    // пересечение
                        coutn++;
                }
                if (coutn != 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Пересекается "+A[i] );
            }

            // объединение (или то, или это)

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: поменял, извините

Comment: объединение это, в каком-то смысле, обратная операция к пересечению, вам достаточно взять код объединения и заменить `coutn != 0` на `coutn == 0`. Естественно это не самые оптимальные варианты реализации, но судя по всему, вам нужно просто что б работало

Comment: @aepot опечатка)

Comment: `coutn == 0` к сожалению так не работает, надо построить правильный вывод, пока не понимаю как

Comment: решил вопрос, добавил вывод